# \SetAlgorithmName in algorithm2e package with a separate counter

Tags: counters, algorithm2e

I'd like to use algorithm2e package to write listing of both **algorithms** and **heuristics**. I would like to use `\SetAlgorithmName` in a way that it would use separate counters for heuristics and algorithms.

So, e.g. I do:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\SetAlgorithmName{Heuristics}

\begin{algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
```

and I get:

**Algorithm 1**

**Heuristic 1**

and not:
**Algorithm 1**

**Heuristic 2**

as currently.

Comment: Is this question still relevant. What about other uses of `algorithm` environment? Do you change the Algorithm name each time before?

Comment: The use of `\SetAlgorithmName` is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach that works if `hyperref` is used (and also if it is not used) and sets the counter name according to the content of `\algorithmcfname` and links correctly.

Just define a counter, say `heuristics` and a macro `\heuristicsname` which contains `Heuristics`. If the counter is named foo, `\fooname` must be defined as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\heuristicsname}{Heuristics}
\newcounter{heuristics}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \let\orighyper@refstepcounter\hyper@refstepcounter%
  \newcommand{\specialhyper@refstepcounter}[1]{%
    \orighyper@refstepcounter{\@specialcountername}%
    \renewcommand{\@currentHref}{\@specialcountername.\csname the\@specialcountername\endcsname}%
  }
}{%
  \providecommand{\autoref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
  \newcommand{\specialhyper@refstepcounter}[1]{%
  }
}

\newcommand{\specialcountername}[1]{%
  \def\@specialcountername{#1}
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{%
\specialcountername{heuristics}%
\edef\temp@@a{\csname\@specialcountername name\endcsname}
\edef\temp@@b{\algorithmcfname}
\ifx\temp@@a\temp@@b
\csletcs{c@algocf}{c@\@specialcountername}
\csletcs{thealgocf}{the\@specialcountername}
\let\hyper@refstepcounter\specialhyper@refstepcounter
\fi
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms


See \ref{algo} and \ref{heu} or \autoref{heu}

\begin{algorithm}
  \KwData{foo}
  \caption{Foo Algorithm} \label{algo}
\end{algorithm}

\SetAlgorithmName{\heuristicsname}{}{}

\clearpage
\begin{algorithm}
  \KwData{foo}
  \caption{Foo Heuristics} \label{heu}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update with improved setup**

Use `\SetupForOtherCounter{foo}{Foo}` to define the new counter name and a new name for the environment caption.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SetupForOtherCounter}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{%
    \newcounter{#1}%
  }{}%
  \@ifundefined{#1name}{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1name\endcsname{#2}
  }{%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1name\endcsname{#2}
  }%
}
\makeatother


\SetupForOtherCounter{heuristics}{Heuristics}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%

\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \let\orighyper@refstepcounter\hyper@refstepcounter%
  \newcommand{\specialhyper@refstepcounter}[1]{%
    \orighyper@refstepcounter{\@specialcountername}%
    \renewcommand{\@currentHref}{\@specialcountername.\csname the\@specialcountername\endcsname}%
  }
}{%
  \providecommand{\autoref}[1]{\ref{#1}}
  \newcommand{\specialhyper@refstepcounter}[1]{%
  }
}


\newcommand{\specialcountername}[1]{%
  \def\@specialcountername{#1}
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{%
\specialcountername{heuristics}%
\edef\temp@@a{\csname\@specialcountername name\endcsname}
\edef\temp@@b{\algorithmcfname}
\ifx\temp@@a\temp@@b
\csletcs{c@algocf}{c@\@specialcountername}
\csletcs{thealgocf}{the\@specialcountername}
\let\hyper@refstepcounter\specialhyper@refstepcounter
\fi
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms


See \ref{algo} and \ref{heu} or \autoref{heu}

\begin{algorithm}
  \KwData{foo}
  \caption{Foo Algorithm} \label{algo}
\end{algorithm}

\SetAlgorithmName{\heuristicsname}{}{}

\clearpage
\begin{algorithm}
  \KwData{foo}
  \caption{Foo Heuristics} \label{heu}
\end{algorithm}



\end{document}
```